# Variable lengths don't match when using ave function in R?

Tags: r

I'm looking to use the `ave` function to apply the `arima()` function over a particular group of my dataframe. The `arima` function, however, requires me to list some variables under the `xreg` argument, but I don't know how to specify the `xreg` variables in such a way that they are the same length as each of the groups separated out by the `ave` function.

Currently:

```
DKmerg
      Player        CPM        Play.at         Team
1  Dave Whitting   0.01111111    away              33
2  Dave Whitting   0.00000000    away              46
3  Dave Whitting   0.02222222    home              60
4  Dave Whitting   0.03333333    away              42
5  Dave Whitting   0.04444444    home              45
6     Aaron Bryann 0.00000000    away              49
7     Aaron Bryann 0.08064516    home              49
8     Aaron Bryann 0.00000000    away              68
9     Aaron Bryann 0.05555556    home              57
10    Aaron Bryann 0.01470588    away              68
11    Aaron Bryann 0.03333333    home              68
12    Aaron Bryann 0.03333333    home              68
13    Aaron Bryann 0.05555556    away              43
14    Aaron Bryann 0.03333333    home              75
15    Aaron Bryann 0.00000000    home              64
16    Mark Johnson 0.11111111    home              62
17    Mark Johnson 0.00000000    away              27
18    Mark Johnson 0.00000000    home              54
19    Mark Johnson 0.03333333    home              51
20    Mark Johnson 0.01333333    away              25

ave(DKmerg$CPM, DKmerg$Player, FUN = function(x) arima(x, order = c(1,0,1), xreg = cbind(DKmerg$Play.at, DKmerg$Team)))
```

leads to an error because the lengths of `x` and `xreg` do not match.

I assume this is because the `xreg` variables are the length of the entire data frame and not the length of the groups broken down by the `ave` function.

How can I change my code to get these object lengths to match?

Comment: Please show a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: does your function work on its own?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes, if I apply it to the whole data frame (i.e. without the ave part) it works fine.

Comment: @akrun I've now edited it with reproducible example

Comment: Isn't it the case that your grouping variable sends one factor's subset at a time to your `FUN` and thus the other arguments to `arima` don't match in length?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yup I think that's the problem, but I don't know a way around it.